# Editing mysql tables/database with wordpress or other app/cms

Tags: mysql, table, cms, phpmyadmin

I have a particular use case which i am not sure is common or suitable to wordpress.

I have built a website without using wordpress using html css javascript and have it connected to a custom mysql database for all my posts data, articles, images etc.

I hate the phpmyadmin mysql interface when updating the values of the mysql tables that control the content of my website and i find it time consuming and innefective. I am looking for a new adding new data to my mysql table and editing existing data.

Is there an easy wordpress solution to this? I have looked at information on the wpDataTables plugin or EditAnyTable plugin for example.

If using such wordpress plugins to edit mysql tables how would you make it as secure as possible (so only the admin can make edits)? I saw some talk about using  wpDataTables on the backend in the WPAdmin Dashboard but this supposedly only can be done with tables that are generated with the TableConstructor feature. That seems kind of limited because i have already existing tables that i built in phpmyadmin that i would like to access. Is that for some reason more secure than creating a front end version with one of these plugins?.  Or would some other type of cms/ web app be more suitable?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that Wordpress really wouldn't be a suitable solution for this. I would look at other MySQL database management tools (Navicat, MyWebSQL, etc..).

Comment: thanks allot for your response ill take a look into that and also welcome any other answers to this question